# How to find out continous numbers?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to find out the continuous numbers(without space) from below

```
123456789,
1  2  3  4 5678,
12 34 56 78,
1234  56,
4782828,
677 56  764,
467  567  675,
```

Output like :

```
123456789,
4782828
```

How can i get the above output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use the `translate()` function to do this check:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT '123456789' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '1  2  3  4 5678' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '12 34 56 78' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '1234  56' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '4782828' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '677 56  764' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '467  567  675' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '4a5' str FROM dual)
SELECT str
FROM   your_table
WHERE  TRANSLATE(str, 'a1234567890', 'a') IS NULL;

STR
---------------
123456789
4782828
```

[`TRANSLATE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions216.htm#SQLRF06145) is a function that allows you to specify a string of characters and a string of characters that you want to translate. I.e. if you want to change all a's into b's etc.

In our case, we want to change all digits into nulls and then check that the resultant string is also null, because that would mean the string contained nothing but digits.

So `TRANSLATE(str, 'a1234567890', 'a')` reads like:

1. take the str field.
2. translate any 'a' characters to 'a'. (We need this step, because the final parameter needs to contain at least one character.)
3. translate any '1' characters to nothing (since the final parameter has no 2nd character).
4. translate any '2' characters to nothing.
   ...
5. translate any '0' characters to nothing.

Therefore a string of `12345` would end up as a null string, but the string `1b2` would end up as `b` since b's aren't affected by the translate.

This method is a lot more flexible than specifying the characters that you want to ignore, because you have a much smaller number of characters you are interested in (9 digits).

Comment: can you explain me ..how it works with translate function @boneist

Comment: @user9293054 I've updated my answer to include an explanation, but you should really take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions216.htm#SQLRF06145) if you don't know how a function works!

Answer (score 2):

If this is a column in a table:

```
select *
from t
where col not like '% %';
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this out

```
    CREATE TABLE recipes ( 
    recipe_name VARCHAR(30));
    INSERT INTO recipes 
    (recipe_name) 
    VALUES 
    ('123456789')
    ,('1  2  3  4 5678')
    ,('12 34 56 78')
    ,('1234  56')
    ,('4782828')
    ,('677 56  764')
    ,('467  567  675')

    SELECT  recipe_name FROM recipes
    where (LEN(recipe_name + '@') - LEN(REPLACE(recipe_name, ' ', '') + '@'))=0
```

Comment: You need to use `||` not `+` to concatenate strings.

Comment: This is the second time (that I know of) where you have answered a question tagged `[oracle]` using non-Oracle syntax. Of course you're trying to be helpful but providing answers that cannot run in the OP's environment is no help to them, and no way for you to accumulate reputation. I suggest you pay attention to the tagging before you answer a question and test your code on the appropriate platform. You will find [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) a tremendous boon in this regard.

Comment: Sorry i am new on the stack overflow.How could i know that its asked for sql or oracle they tag both of them and as i know this platform is all about the idea to resolve the problem not the complete solution so my answer should treat as suggestion not the solution for the other database user.

Comment: The SQL tag is for Structured Query Language (SQL), it doesn't refer to SQL Server. If someone is asking for SQL help, the database platform is important, since they all use slightly different flavours of SQL. Answering a question on a specific database platform with SQL that only works on a different database platform is not very useful.